# Python: NameError: name is not defined even though it is defined

Tags: python

I have the code below. When I try to run it, I get the error below. How do I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for the help:)

```
    imageList = [f for f in listdir(imageFolder) if isfile(join(imageFolder, f))]
NameError: name 'imageFolder' is not defined
```

```
class TestItem:
    current_milli_time = None
    Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    Config.read("sample.ini")

    accessKey = Config.get("project", "accessKey")
    deploymentID = Config.get("project", "deploymentID")
    imageFolder = Config.get("test", "imageFolder")

    imageList = [f for f in listdir(imageFolder) if isfile(join(imageFolder, f))]
    def ready_upload(self):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ItemTest= TestItem()
    ItemTest.ready_upload()
```

Comment: You only need to do that if you're accessing the variable from outside the class.

Comment: Where's the body of `ready_upload`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to write a constructor for your class. In that case, you just need to put the constructor code under the special method `__init__()`.

```py
class TestItem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_milli_time = None
        Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        Config.read("sample.ini")

        self.accessKey = Config.get("project", "accessKey")
        self.deploymentID = Config.get("project", "deploymentID")
        self.imageFolder = Config.get("test", "imageFolder")

        self.imageList = [f for f in listdir(self.imageFolder) if isfile(join(self.imageFolder, f))]

    def ready_upload(self):
        # do something with self.imageList, etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ItemTest = TestItem()
    ItemTest.ready_upload()
```